# How do I set the background color of a FormControlLabel if it's selected in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

if I have a `RadioGroup` and want to make the background color of the checked radio button to another color, how do I do this in Material UI? Can't find anything in the documentation.

```
<FormControlLabel
  key={key}
  value={value}
  control={<Radio />}
  label={label}
/>
```

If I try the code below, only the radio button itself gets background color black, not the entire label.

```
<FormControlLabel
      key={obj.value}
      value={obj.value}
      control={
        <Radio
          sx={{
            '&.Mui-checked': {
              backgroundColor: 'black',
            },
          }}
        />
      }
      label={obj.label}
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found some useful information in the docs.

By using the useRadioGroup() hook we get more control over the appearance of the radio group.

Inspired by an [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/#api) from the documentation, I found this solution to your question.

Live demo:

[image: Edit Change background of slected MUI Radio]

Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import RadioGroup, { useRadioGroup } from "@mui/material/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel, {
  FormControlLabelProps
} from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";

function MyFormControlLabel(props: FormControlLabelProps) {
  const radioGroup = useRadioGroup();

  let checked = false;

  if (radioGroup) {
    checked = radioGroup.value === props.value;
  }

  if (checked)
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.light
        }}
        checked={checked}
        {...props}
      />
    );

  return <FormControlLabel checked={checked} {...props} />;
}

export default function UseRadioGroup() {
  return (
    <RadioGroup name="use-radio-group" defaultValue="first">
      <MyFormControlLabel value="first" label="First" control={<Radio />} />
      <MyFormControlLabel value="second" label="Second" control={<Radio />} />
    </RadioGroup>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little tweak from the [Mui example documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/#useradiogroup) and the previous answer you can change the background of a selected radio button by changing what class you're trying to reference.

In the Mui Docs example they change the color of the text by referencing **".MuiFormControlLabel-label"**

```
const StyledFormControlLabel = styled((props) => <FormControlLabel {...props} />)(
  ({ theme, checked }) => ({
    '.MuiFormControlLabel-label': checked && {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  }),
);
```

use **"&.MuiFormControlLabel-root"** instead to gain access to both the background and the text.

```
const StyledFormControlLabel = styled((props) => <FormControlLabel {...props} />)(
  ({ theme, checked }) => ({
    '&.MuiFormControlLabel-root': checked && {

      //changing text color
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,

      //changing background color and shape
      backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
      borderRadius: "15px",
    },
  })
);
```

Full Implementation:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import RadioGroup, { useRadioGroup } from "@mui/material/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Radio from "@mui/material/Radio";

constStyledFormControlLabel = styled((props) => <FormControlLabel {...props} />)(
  ({ theme, checked }) => ({
    '&.MuiFormControlLabel-root': checked && {

      //changing text color
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,

      //changing background color and shape
      backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
      borderRadius: "15px",
    },
  })
);

function MyFormControlLabel(props) {
  const radioGroup = useRadioGroup();

  let checked = false;

  if (radioGroup) {
    checked = radioGroup.value === props.value;
  }

  return <StyledFormControlLabel checked={checked} {...props} />;
}

export default function UseRadioGroup() {
  return (
    <RadioGroup name="use-radio-group" defaultValue="first">
      <MyFormControlLabel value="first" label="First" control={<Radio />} />
      <MyFormControlLabel value="second" label="Second" control={<Radio />} />
    </RadioGroup>
  );
}
```

If you're preserving the state of the `RadioGroup` after moving to another page (e.g. Use Case: A user wants to backtrack on a multi-page form). Then this solution will keep your custom style binded to your `RadioGroup` state on render.